# Exclude certain taxonomy from function

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a help with a WordPress code.
On this page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/ I got a code that returns my taxonomies and their terms.

But I'd like a certain taxonomy called "Ad Type" to be excluded from this list.

I managed to exclude some terms from "Ad Type" using this code...

```
// An array of IDs to ignore / exclude
$ excluded_ids = array (1, 2, 3, 4);

foreach ($ terms as $ term) {
// Only proceed if the term_id is NOT in the $ excluded_ids array
   if (! in_array ($ term-> term_id, $ excluded_ids)) {
   $ out. = '<li> <a href="' .get_term_link($term-> slug, $ taxonomy).' '>'. $ term-> name. '</a> </ li>';
}
}
```

But what I want is that the "Ad Type" taxonomy does not appear at all.
Because with the code above the Title of "Ad Type" is still appearing on the terms list retrieved.
What i want is to totally exlcude this taxonomy from being retrieved on that part of my wordpress template.

Here is the code:

```
function wpdocs_custom_taxonomies_terms_links() {
// Get post by post ID.
$post = get_post( $post->ID );

// Get post type by post.
$post_type = $post->post_type;

// Get post type taxonomies.
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' );

$out = array();

foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){

    // Get the terms related to post.
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );

    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

        $out[] = "<h6>" . $taxonomy->label . ":</h6>\n<ul>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $out[] = sprintf( '<li>%2$s</li> - ',
                esc_url( get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) ),
                esc_html( $term->name )
            );
        }
        $out[] = "</ul>\n";
    }
}

return implode( '', $out ); 
}
```

And here is how i retrieve it on my template page:

```
<?php echo wpdocs_custom_taxonomies_terms_links(); ?>
```

Is there a way to do this?
can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, because you say "totally exclude the taxonomy from being returned", and you have two separate code blocks.  So - the function `get_the_terms()` does not allow excluding a term type, _except_ if you were to use a filter on it (but that filter would be run every time get_the_terms is called, including any admin-side calls).  Is it acceptable for the "exclusion" to happen inside your function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am comparing it right but you can check if current taxonomy is not `Ad Type` only then get terms

```
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){

    if ($taxonomy_slug !== 'ad_type') :
        // Get the terms related to post.
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

            $out[] = "<h6>" . $taxonomy->label . ":</h6>\n<ul>";
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $out[] = sprintf( '<li>%2$s</li> - ',
                    esc_url( get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) ),
                    esc_html( $term->name )
                );
            }
            $out[] = "</ul>\n";
        }
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the desired term(s) by adding `if ($term->term_id == 30) continue;` as shown below, where 30 and 31 are the IDs of excluded terms.

```
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){

    // Get the terms related to post.
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );

    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {                 
        $out[] = "<h6>" . $taxonomy->label . ":</h6>\n<ul>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
              //Excluded terms, change the IDs as you wish
              if ($term->term_id == 30) continue;
              if ($term->term_id == 31) continue;
            $out[] = sprintf( '<li>%2$s</li> - ',
                esc_url( get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) ),
                esc_html( $term->name )
            );
        }
        $out[] = "</ul>\n";
    }
}

return implode( '', $out ); 
}
```